# jQuery Datepicker. 2 datepickers. Restrict range: Max date of 2 weeks from the selected start date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have 2 datepickers "from" & "to". I want to restrict the date range so that for whatever date is selected for the "from" datepicker, the "to" datepicker is restricted to within 2 weeks from that selected "from" date.

For Example: I select 07-15-2018 in "from" datepicker, and I can only select up to 07-29-2018 in "to" datepicker.

> Current DatePicker Code:

```
<script> $( function() {

var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
  from = $( "#from" )
    .datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      minDate: 0
    })
    .on( "change", function() {


     to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) ); 

    }),
  to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1
  })
  .on( "change", function() {
    from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
  });

function getDate( element ) {
  var date;
  try {
    date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
  } catch( error ) {
    date = null;
  }

  return date;
}
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help. On selecting a date in the datepicker, add 2 weeks to the date and set it to the `to` date.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#from").datepicker({
        onSelect:function(value){
            var date = new Date(value);
            date.setDate(date.getDate()+14);
            $("#to").datepicker("setDate",date)
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input id="from">
<input id="to">
```

Comment: @bryce Does this helped you ?